# how to declare query set in model.py

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to have a query set in my models.py so that I can access it over admin view and also the templates. The problem I'm having is to declare the query set in admin.py and also view.py differently. I want a single query set which I can access it anywhere

Here is my code in admin.py

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ItemTableAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(
       stock=(F('amount') - F('consumption'))
    )
    return qs

def stock(self, obj):
    return obj.stock
```

and here is my code in views.py

```
my_models = list(ItemTable.objects.all().annotate(stock=(F('amount') - 
F('consumption'))))

my_models_table = items(my_models)
RequestConfig(request).configure(my_models_table)
```

which is giving me same result also in admin panel and template.
ex:
   8.00 - 7.00 = 1.00

Now here is my code in model.py which is to achieve the same goal and get access both in admin and template

```
from django.db.models import F

class ItemTable(models.Model):
    refno = models.CharField("Reference No", max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)
    slno = models.CharField("Serial No", max_length=50, null=False)
    date = models.DateField("Entry Date")
    mata_name = models.TextField("Name of Materials", blank=True)
    manu_name = models.CharField("Manufacturer Name", max_length=50, blank=True)
    batch_no = models.CharField("Batch No", max_length=50, blank=True)
    product = models.TextField("Used in Product", blank=True)
    agent = models.CharField("Local Agent", max_length=250, blank=True)
    mfgdate = models.DateField("MFG Date", null=True, blank=True)
    expdate = models.DateField("EXP Date", null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4, blank=True, null=True)
    consumption = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4, blank=True, null=True)
    coa = models.FileField("Certificate of Analysis", upload_to='pdf/coa', blank=True, null=True)
    msds = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf/msds', blank=True, null=True)
    moa = models.FileField("Method of Analysis", upload_to='pdf/moa', blank=True, null=True)


    def query(self):
        return ItemTable.objects.all().annotate(stock=F('amount') - 
        F('consumption'))
```

I expect the output like 8.00 - 7.00 = 1.00, but I'm getting this output:

```
<QuerySet [<ItemTable: 12>, <ItemTable: 1>, <ItemTable: 2>, <ItemTable: 3>, <ItemTable: 4>, <ItemTable: 5>]>
```

Comment: Are you defining the above `query` method in `ItemTable` model in `models.py`?

Comment: Yes. That’s what I’m doing.

Comment: Just for the conventions, this not the right place to do so. You should define this in `managers`. Did you try this in Django shell? Can you show the complete `ItemTable` model?

Comment: I'm just guessing. I think you are getting the right objects but their string representation can be wrong. I mean that `12`, `1`, etc can be ids.

Comment: No I didn't try this in django shell. 
I've edited the model for you to see.I hope it helps.

Comment: You guessed right. They are my models id. but about string representation I've no idea.

Comment: Just to confirm are you trying to calculate the difference between amount and consumption for every entry in this model?

Comment: Yes I’m trying to calculate the difference between amount and consumption for every entry in this model.

Comment: Then you are correct. Just iterate through the result and print `amount`, `consumption` and `stock` for each object. QuerySet is a type of list.

Comment: can you show some example please?